# Replacing a specific whitespace pattern in sed with a newline, when it doesn't have a preceding colon?

Tags: regex, sed

I am trying to parse the following line using sed to replace a whitespace with a newline only when the whitespace doesn't precede a colon.

For example, I'm using the following input to be processed:

```
label1: output label2: output2 label3: "output3" label4: output4 { label5: output5 label6: output6 } label7: output7 { { { label8: output8 } label9: output9 } } label10: output10
```

I'd like regex to replace any whitespace that doesn't have a colon before it with a newline, so the output would be something like this:

```
label1: output
label2: output2
label3: "output3"
label4: output4
{
label5: output5
label6: output6
}
label7: output7
{
{
{
label8: output8
label9: output9
}
}
label10: output10
```

When I try using the following regex in `cat file | sed 's/[^:A-Za-z0-9\"] /%/g' | tr '%' '\n'`, it results in the output below, which is close but not achieving the goal:

```
    label1: output label2: output2 label3: "output3" label4: output4
    label5: output5 label6: output6
    label7: output7


    label8: output8
    label9: output9

    label10: output10
```

I've also tried this `cat file | sed 's/[^:A-Za-z0-9\"] /%/g' | tr '%' '\n'`, and it results in

```
label1: outpu
label2: output
label3: "output3
label4: output

label5: output
label6: output

label7: output



label8: output

label9: output


label10: output10
```

Which looks like the regex also includes replacing every other character that's not a `:` with a newline.

Comment: You want to avoid the [useless use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Comment: The regular expression for "not a colon (or a newline)" is `[^:]`; it's not clear from your question if you also want newlines followed by space to be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
sed -E 's/([^:]) /\1\n/g' file
```

Output:

```
label1: output
label2: output2
label3: "output3"
label4: output4
{
label5: output5
label6: output6
}
label7: output7
{
{
{
label8: output8
}
label9: output9
}
}
label10: output10
```

Cheers!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your answer need more explanation about how the code works to be a good answer.

Comment: The `-r` option is not portable; not all `sed` variants support the escape `\n` for literal newline.

Comment: Changed the -r option to -E. Not sure how to address your comment about \n

Comment: `-E` is also not portable; both of these are outside of the POSIX spec. There is a way to embed a literal newline in a `sed` script but how exactly to do that isn't completely portable, either (typically, backslash-newline works most places).

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'G;:a;s/\([^: ]\) \(.*\(.\)\)/\1\3\2/;ta;s/.$//' file
```

Append a newline to the current line using the `G` command which by default appends an empty hold space to the pattern space. Using pattern matching and back references, iterate throughout the current line replacing a non-space/non-colon character followed by a space, by the appended newline. When there are no further matches, remove the newline artefact and print the line.

The same solution can be viewed more easily using the `-r` option (GNU sed only) which removes many of back slashes:

```
sed  -r 'G;:a;s/([^: ]) (.*(.))/\1\3\2/;ta;s/.$//' file
```

Also as pointed out, the optimal solution would be:

```
sed  's/\([^: ]\) /\1\n/g' file
```